# Specific key count in json jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json in that there will be key it can exists or not in the jason data .Now what i want to get total number of existence of the key in jquery.

JSON :

```
jasonData = [{"test":"sa3"},{"test":"4s"},{"acf":"1s"},{"test":"6s"}];
```

How can we do this in jquery please help me in this

Comment: What is your expected result.

Comment: @MadhuMagar three will be the total count as final result

Comment: @MadhuMagar i don't want to use foreach for this

Comment: Just try `jasonData.length`

Comment: @PoojaDubey can you show the sampe json output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this:

```js
var jasonData = [{"test":"sa3"},{"test":"4s"},{"acf":"1s"},{"test":"6s"}];
var count = jasonData.filter(function(element) {
    return element.test;
}).length;
document.write(count);
```

Or, for further cross-browser compatibility, jQuery provides a similar [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) function:

```js
var jasonData = [{"test":"sa3"},{"test":"4s"},{"acf":"1s"},{"test":"6s"}];
var count = $.grep(jasonData, function(element) {
    return element.test;
}).length;
document.write(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery needed

This will give you an object showing each key and the number of times it occurs

```js
var jasonData = [{"test":"sa3"},{"test":"4s"},{"acf":"1s"},{"test":"6s"}];
var keyCounts = {};

for (var i = 0; i < jasonData.length; i++) {
  var key = Object.keys(jasonData[i])[0];
  if (typeof(keyCounts[key]) == 'undefined') {
    keyCounts[key] = 1;
  } else {
    keyCounts[key] += 1;
  }
}

console.log(keyCounts);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in core JS as well...

Here is the running code.

```js
var jasonData = [{"test":"sa3"},{"test":"4s"},{"acf":"1s"},{"test":"6s"}];
var sum=0;
jasonData.forEach(function(value,i){
  if(value.test){
    sum++;  
  }
});
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a very simple way ::

```
var tempArr = [{"test":"sa3"},{"test":"4s"},{"acf":"1s"},{"test":"6s"}];
var tempObj;

for(var i=0;i<tempArr.length;i++){
    tempObj = tempArr[i];
    for(key in tempObj){
        alert("key : "+key +"value  : "+tempObj[key]);
    }
}
```

This way you can get any no of keys and values in any json array. Now tweak this code according to your requirement like increase and decrease the count or whatever you want to do.

Hope you got the approach !!!